# EXCEL:: Can I use =TODAY() function in INDEX reference function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Like the title, can I use =TODAY() function in INDEX reference?

At cell, I made INDEX function like this

**INDEX('C:\files[THE_LIST_YYMMDD.xlsx]thelist'!$AO:$AO,MATCH($A$15,'C:\files[THE_LIST_YYMMDD.xlsx]thelist'!$Y:$Y,0))**

And I want to put today's YYMMDD at file reference [THE_LIST_YYMMDD.xlsx]. Is there any way to put function in file reference? Like =TODAY() function?

Answer (score 2):

By using `TEXT(TODAY(),"YYMMDD")` inside an `INDIRECT` function:

`=INDEX(INDIRECT("'C:\files[THE_LIST_"&TEXT(TODAY(),"YYMMDD")&".xlsx]thelist'!$AO:$AO"),MATCH($A$15, INDIRECT (""'C:\files[THE_LIST_"&TEXT(TODAY(),"YYMMDD")&".xlsx]thelist'!$Y:$Y"),0))`